# When the orientation change from portrait to landscape, the video starts from the beginning in Android?

Tags: android, video

I am writing an Android project, at beginning I am playing a video in portrait mode, a few seconds later when i change it **from portrait to landscape**, the video starts from the beginning(**0's**)? why?

I have set `android:configChanges="orientation"` in AndroidManifest.xml and added `onConfigurationChanged()`.

How to let it play from the last position of portrait mode while the mode changes?

Comment: what parameter you've passed to `onSaveInstanceState()` to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState` are the methods meant to remember and restore the current state when a configuration change occurs like e.g. a screen orientation change.

Refer the link - https://stackoverflow.com/a/151940/28557

Comment: Thank you for the link. Could you kindly give the command which makes the activity to remember the video paused position. what we should add in extras

Answer (score 0):

The general way of android to handle the orientation is recreating the entire activity.

If you whant to handle yourself you have to modify the AndroidManifest.xml and set this attribute to the activity node:

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

More information in [this](http://www.gitshah.com/2011/03/how-to-handle-screen-orientation_28.html) post

Comment: I have set android:configChanges="orientation" in AndroidManifest.xml and added onConfigurationChanged()! sorry, i forgot to say

Comment: was the data lost when the layout changes, though activity has not been destroyed?

Answer (score 0):

actually when you change change the orientation of screen the activity is first destroyed and then recreated it. you should check activity life cycle methods by grammatically.

Comment: I have set android:configChanges="orientation" in AndroidManifest.xml, so the activity will not be recreated.